# Counts from 3 tables with 2 left joins and 1 composite primary key

Tags: mysql, logic

I have 3 tables like this

```
SecretAgents

| id | name |
|----|------|
| 1  |  A   |
| 2  |  B   |

Victims

| id | name | agent_id |
|----|------|----------|
|  1 |  Z   |   1      |
|  2 |  Y   |   1      |
|  3 |  X   |   2      |

Data
| id | keys | values | victim_id | form_id |
|----|------|--------|-----------|---------|
| 1  |  a1  |   x    |    1      |   1     |
| 2  |  a2  |   xx   |    1      |   2     |
| 3  |  a3  |   xxx  |    2      |   1     |
| 4  |  a5  |   xxx  |    1      |   1     |
```

I have to get the count of forms(here victim_id and form_id are composite primary keys) and the count of victims for each agent.

I have tried this for any 2 tables with left joins and group by but I am not able to achieve the same together. If anyone can be generous enough to offer a pointer/solution, that would be super awesome..

**EDIT 1: The query**

This is definitely not the right query but anyways

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT v.id) as victimcount, `sa`.`username`, `sa`.`id`, count(DISTINCT d.form_id) as submissions
FROM `SecretAgents` as `sa`
LEFT JOIN `Victims` as `v` ON `v`.`agent_id`=`sa`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `Data` as `d` ON `d`.`victim_id`=`v`.`id`
GROUP BY `v`.`agent_id`
ORDER BY `sa`.`id` ASC
```

The victimcount is correct but the submissions count becomes wrong. Tried lots of other things too but this is the most relevant...

Thanks

Comment: I have tried lots of ways, none of them are correct, but still i will paste the wrong query. Maybe someone might get the point I am missing...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can count the forms-per-agent like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as form_count, a.id as id, a.name as agent 
    FROM Data d 
    LEFT JOIN Victims v ON v.id = d.victim_id
    LEFT JOIN SecretAgents a on v.agent_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

To count the victims, just leave off the Data table.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem with this query is the data table stores key-value pairs and the victim_id and form_id form a composite primary key. I had tried this but this gives a wrong count. Thought of a solution using group by on the victim and forms but then the group by agent is lost. The more I think the more confusing it gets...